# keyboard cover for iPad Mini 2019 (gen 5)

Tags: ipad, keyboard

I recently bought an iPad Mini 5. I'm now trying to find a keyboard cover/stand that I can use to more easily watch videos and play games without having to constantly support the screen. I know Logitech makes them but they haven't yet come out with a model that supports gen 5 (reference?), and I was told by a store clerk at a local retailer that the Gen 4 models aren't compatible since hardware buttons have moved (which buttons - the key caps?). [Per this chat thread](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50620235#50620235), here are my requirements.

The must have is connectivity and one standard USB charging connector

Nice to have are:

- printed AZERTY keyboard layout (even better if it's Belgian AZERTY) so I don’t have to use software layouts or modify the keys
- reliable bluetooth wireless connection to the iPad
- reasonably long battery life
- major brand that's known for quality and honoring warranty service without hassle
- charging port is lightning, micro USB second preferred

What brand and model would you recommend if you have experience knowing one works. Better, how can I understand what requirements / features are needed to evaluate which keyboards will work at all so I can then shop for price on the nice to have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, no one is making the cover you want in June 2019. You might need to get a cover and a keyboard if you don't want to wait.

Here are the keyboards I'd get if you need that first or can't wait:

Apple's actual keyboard nails your requirements for exact keyboard layout, bluetooth support, lightning charging, major brand known for quality keyboards (setting aside people’s love hate MacBook Butterfly keyboard issues)

- https://www.apple.com/be-fr/shop/product/MLA22F/A/magic-keyboard-fran%C3%A7ais

Apple’s bluetooth magic keyboard comes with and without numeric keyboards and also in space grey if you want to spend a bit more. They are not the same size as the mini (feature and/or bug) and you’ll get the best support since Apple made both software, firmware and hardware. If that doesn’t work, Apple has no excuse they didn’t expect you to use these together.

- https://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/ultrathin-keyboard-folio-for-ipad-mini

Logitech would by my next iPad mini specific recommendation. Solid, great warranty, sized right, support for iOS explicitly and you might even score a European model key layout.

I haven’t seen this yet in person, but am tempted to buy it sight-unseen knowing it’s featured at Apple Retail and from a trusted vendor.

- [Logitech Keys-to-Go Ultra Slim Keyboard with iPhone Stand](https://store.apple.com/xc/product/HLPU2PA/A)

Comment: I really want it to be a combo cover/keyboard, because it's meant to also protect the screen of the device during transport and storage. Right now there's gettting a lot of dust on the screen, which I'd like to avoid. The second and 3rd one are out of stock, and I'm not entirely sure they're compatible with the 5th gen iPad mini since that has a different edge button layout compared to the 4th gen.

Comment: Short term, you'll need to just get a case to protect the mini and a separate keyboard from what my research shows. Hopefully someone will bring to market exactly the device you hope to own.